# Nginx SSL Configuration for Multiple Domains & Subdomains

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am configuring Nginx to map `wiki.my-domain.com` to port 3000 and rewrite `my-domain.com` to `wiki.my-domain.com`. I came up with a configuration that works correctly:

1. Create `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.header`:

```
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
if ($scheme != https) {
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://$server_name/$1 permanent;
}
ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate_key.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
```

2. In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
        server {
                server_name my-domain.com;
                include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.header;
                rewrite ^/(.*) https://wiki.my-domain.com/$1 permanent;
        }

        server {
                server_name wiki.my-domain.com;
                include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.header;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_connect_timeout      300;
                        proxy_send_timeout         300;
                        proxy_read_timeout         300;
                }
        }
```

However, as I plan to add more subdomains in the future, and that the SSL certificate key in `conf.d/nginx.header` is only for `wiki.my-domain.com`, I moved the two lines describing `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` from `conf.d/nginx.header` to `nginx.conf`. `nginx.conf` becomes:

```
        server {
                server_name my-domain.com;
                include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.header; # eliminated description of ssl_certification
                rewrite ^/(.*) https://wiki.my-domain.com/$1 permanent;
        }

        server {
                server_name wiki.my-domain.com;
                include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.header; # eliminated description of ssl_certification
                ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate_key.pem;
                location / {
                        # Same as above
                }
        }
```

After this change and reloading nginx, I cannot access the webpage hosted on `wiki.my-domain.com`, and `my-domain.com` is no longer rewritten to `wiki.my-domain.com` in my browser. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your configuration using `nginx -t`, but you have not defined a certificate for `server_name my-domain.com;`

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried adding the certificate for ```my-domain.com``` and it worked. Two questions though: 1) Why does a missing certificate for the first server influence whether the second one would work or not? 2) The first ```my-domain.com``` is a direct rewrite. Why need a certificate?

Comment: (1) If there is an error Nginx will not start, (2) the browser must negotiate a valid SSL connection before it can receive the instruction to redirect to another site.